# How cast RSAPublicKey to CaviumRSAPublicKey in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, security, hsm

I have next code
I load key

```
public static RSAPublicKey getKey(String filename)
            throws Exception {

            byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename));

            X509EncodedKeySpec spec =
              new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            return (RSAPublicKey)kf.generatePublic(spec);
    }
```

I call method

```
RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) GeneraKeysRsa.getKey(file);
```

Now i try cast RSAPublicKey to CaviumRSAPublicKey

```
CaviumRSAPublicKey key = (CaviumRSAPublicKey) pubKey;
```

But i get the next:

```
ClassCastException: sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl cannot be cast to com.cavium.key.CaviumRSAPublicKey
```

Any idea?

Thanks.